# Insert a div-like element inside a table without applying table layout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table (render by datatable) and I need to dymatically append some new elements inside the table like :

[image: WANT TO DO]

The dark grey area is a new dom elements that I need to dynamically insert.

The first row is a title that is **NOT align with the th/td**, which now becomes a problem to be solved

I tried inserting a div that wrap the title inside the table, but the table seems to treat it as a td:

[image: What I tried]

[image: Problem]

We can see that the first row is apparently become much wider , which is not I want.

Is there a simple way to insert something inside but without treat it as td?

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate what I am faced with :http://code.hcharts.cn/jaskey/hhhGXD

Comment: can you share a fiddle?

Comment: @gurvinder372, please check to see the probelm: http://code.hcharts.cn/jaskey/hhhGXD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not able to update your fiddle, try this code

```
$(function () {
    $('#btn').off('click').on('click',function(){
        console.log('click');
        $('#table').find('tr:first-child').after('<tr><td colspan="5"><div>Here I insert a din just after the th, which will be consided as a td ,which breaks the existing layout</div></td></tr>')
    });
});
```

also ensure that you have given specific `width` to `td`'s or `tr` if you don't want them to spread out.

Comment: Thank you! It works. Since we are blocked by the wall so I can't get access to fiddle, if possible, you can copy the code to fiddle to share your result.